# How to get WXpython 2.8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I'm using python and anaconda to work on some code, which turns out to requires wx2.8, but all I can find is installer for wx3.0.

I looked into it, and the process for building an older version of wx from source is very unclear.  It's not as simple as python setup.py install for example.  Does anyone have experience with this, or at least can provides some reading on the matter that they know for a fact works?  **I'm also not using my system python**, so I can't do sudo apt-get install (unless you can specify the python installation path in such a way).

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

`sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using system python, I'm using anaconda.  I'm actually using a virtual environment.  Can I pass a full path to where my python directory is and have apt-get install find it?  Like if my python launcher is in /path/to/other/python, something like sudo apt-get install -o /path/to/other/python ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find wxPython 2.8 using apt-get or Synaptic.

Once wxPython is installed, you can use **wxredirect.pth** to tell your virtualenv to use a custom path to your wxPython install. This [article](http://batok.github.io/virtualenvwxp/) describes a way to hack your virtualenv to point to your wxPython install.

The alternate method would be to create your virtual environment, download the wxPython source and then build it within your virtualenv. I found the following steps [here](http://codersbuffet.blogspot.com/2009/09/wxpython-in-virtualenv.html):

1. cd $HOME
2. tar -xjf wxPython-src-2.8.10.1.tar.bz2
3. cd wxPython-src-2.8.10.1
4. patch -p0 < $HOME/wxpatch.txt
5. ./configure --prefix=$PATH_TO_VENV --with-gtk=2 --enable-unicode --with opengl
6. make install
7. cd contrib/src/stc
8. make install
9. cd ../gizmos
10. make install
11. cd ../../../wxPython
12. python setup.py install

The Phoenix version of wxPython is much easier to use in a virtualenv because it supports pip. However, Phoenix is very beta right now as it's only a partial port, so use that version with caution.

Comment: Thank you!  Let me try it out and then I'll come and mark this accepted and assign bounty.  Super appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answers were helpful, but I had a small hiccup with each approach, I think it might be that I'm using 2.8.12 and those old solutions were no longer valid.  Furthermore, hacking it into the venv was for macOS and I coudln't quite follow on my box.  Anyway, I ended just making a symbolic link after installing system python as Ben suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n
```

Then made my symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wxversion.py <virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wxversion.py
```

Where virutal_evn_path is /home/adam/anaconda/enva/fibersim in my case.  If I wasn't such a linux noob, this answer probably would have been a more obvious workaround.